# Redirecting output and then doing cat doesn't work?

Tags: linux, cat

When i write the below line in terminal it doesn't work

./a.out < filename.txt | cat filename.txt

Pipelining does not work. The process gets terminated after executing

./a.out < filename.txt but doesn't go to cat.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give a little more detail about what it is you're trying to do?  What will happen when it works?

Comment: I wrote a program which takes input from filename.txt and prints the input in reverse order but after that i want to print the contents of filename.txt file but thats not happening with pipelining.

Comment: If the program prints the input in reverse order you should not need to pipe anything...

Comment: If you just want to print it as-is after, simply go: `./a.out <filename.txt; cat filename.txt`. Do you want the contents of filename.txt modified? Then it would be `/a.out <filename.txt >filename.txt; cat filename.txt`

Comment: I want to use pipelining so the there is no point of doing from the above method.

Comment: @CodeHacker: So maybe `cat filename.txt | tee >( ./a.out )`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the input of `a.out` from a pipe, you have to revert the commands:

```
cat filename.txt | ./a.out
```

This construct is called "useless use of cat", though, as it's a slower equivalent of

```
./a.out < filename.txt
```

Comment: @CodeHacker: The pipe is one-directional, left-to-right. `cat` is rarely involved in pipes, though, more common example would be e.g. `grep username: users.txt | cut -d: -f2`

Comment: Even if it is rarely used it should work right because functionality never changes

Comment: @CodeHacker: The other way works correctly: `./a.out filename.txt | cat`. What do you want to connect to the input end of the pipe, and what do you want to connect to the output end?

Comment: What will cat print in that case?

Comment: @CodeHacker: What comes to it through the pipe.

Comment: okay so output of ./a.out filename.txt gets printed by cat is what you are telling, sorry i thought it wont work but it works.

Comment: But still why does ./a.out < filename.txt | cat filename.txt doesn't work i still dont understand?

Comment: @CodeHacker: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What do you want to connect to both the ends of the pipe?

Comment: I meant is the process gets terminated after executing ./a.out < filename.txt it doesn't to go pipelining.

Comment: Is pipelining not working because am not passing anything through it?

Comment: @CodeHacker: If you don't pass anything to a pipeline, you can't get anything out of it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, and I'm not being facetious here, the easiest, most straightforward way to do this seems to me to be:

```
a.out filename.txt && cat filename.txt
```

or, if a.out only reads stdin,

```
cat filename.txt | a.out && cat filename.txt
```